# Cannot obtain address via DHCP

Tags: networking, solaris

I recently upgraded this box from Solaris 11.2 to Solaris 11.3. After that I cannot get an interface to obtain an IP address from within a non-global zone.

From the global zone I have the following interfaces:

```
root@myserver:/# dladm
LINK                CLASS     MTU    STATE    OVER
net0                phys      1500   up       --
net2                phys      1500   up       --
zone1/net0          vnic      1500   up       net0
zone1/net2          vnic      1500   up       net2
```

And in the global zone I can obtain an address via DHCP for the interface `net2` without problems:

```
root@myserver:/# ipadm
NAME              CLASS/TYPE STATE        UNDER      ADDR
lo0               loopback   ok           --         --
   lo0/v4         static     ok           --         127.0.0.1/8
   lo0/v6         static     ok           --         ::1/128
net0              ip         ok           --         --
   net0/v4        static     ok           --         192.168.1.55/24
net2              ip         ok           --         --
   net2/v4        dhcp       ok           --         192.168.10.4/24
```

And then we add my zone, `zone1` to the mix. This zone uses exclusive-ip and uses `net2` as a vnic.

```
root@zone1:~# dladm
LINK                CLASS     MTU    STATE    OVER
net0                vnic      1500   up       ?
net2                vnic      1500   up       ?


root@zone1:~# ipadm
NAME              CLASS/TYPE STATE        UNDER      ADDR
lo0               loopback   ok           --         --
   lo0/v4         static     ok           --         127.0.0.1/8
   lo0/v6         static     ok           --         ::1/128
net0              ip         ok           --         --
   net0/v4        static     ok           --         192.168.1.60/24
net2              ip         ok           --         --
   net2/v4        dhcp       ok           --         ?
```

So why can't `net2` obtain an address via DHCP in this zone ?

This has worked for me for 2-3 years. After upgrade to Solaris 11.3 it suddenly no longer works. Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you snoop the DHCP traffic to see how far it gets?

Comment: Maybe I can go wrong, but the exclusive-ip zone has the same nic as the gz? Can you post a `zoneadm list -vic`?

Answer (score 0):

The `net2` link for a non-global zone does not necessarily be the same link as for the global zone.

Use `dladm show-link -z zonename` to identify which link of the zone is using which 'lower-link'. For instance:

```
$ dladm show-link -z myzone
LINK                CLASS     MTU    STATE    OVER
myzone/net2         vnic      1500   up       net0
```

See how the link for the zone is configured using:

```
$ zonecfg -z myzone info anet| egrep "linkname|lower-link"
```

If the 'lower-link' is set to auto Solaris tries to determine which interface should be used but this may not always be what you expect.